# select all from table1 and just one column from table2

Tags: sql

I have this query:

```
select *, U.TYPE from table1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS U ON (U.ID=ID)
```

what it does is it gives me ALL columns from table1 and table2. Is there a neater way of getting ALL columns form table1 and just that one column from table2 besides listing all the fields from table1 in the select statement rather than putting the * ?

Comment: `select TABLE1.*, U.TYPE from table1 LEFT JOIN table2 AS U ON (U.ID=ID)`

Comment: are you kidding me!?!?!?! is it that simple!?!?! I feel like an idiot! thank you! how did I not think of this myself. feeling stupid ;/  go ahead and post that as an answer and I'll exept it as the answer and up it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff no, it does, op was using `SELECT *, u.type`, so it first returned every column from both tables

Comment: Don't worry @MikePala, every single one of us had one or more of these moments at some point :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
select a.*, b.TYPE from table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON (a.ID=b.ID)
```